# Node.js Express app insert app.local.setting only once when logged in

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a node.js + Express app. I am using Passport for user login. There is a system settings table in my database which I want to read from when a user successfully logs in and then create app.locals.setting_name local variables from it, which will be used during the lifetime of the application.

The settings table has the Name and Value columns which represent the setting name and its corresponding value. So something like: Name - SUPPORT_EMAIL and Value - support@email.com, as an example.

So I would have app.locals.SUPPORT_EMAIL value set as support@email.com

Here is the code I have so far:

**app.js**

```
var settingsObj = require('./config/appSettings.js');
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    ...
    ...
    settingsObj.getApplicationSystemSetting(req.user, app);
    next();
});
```

**appSettings.js**

```
exports.getApplicationSystemSetting = function() {
    connectionPool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
        connection.query('select Name, Value from SystemSettings', function(err, rows){
            if(err) {
                winston.log('info', '--------------------- ERROR: ' + err);
                return;
            }

            console.log('-------------- settings: ' + JSON.stringify(rows));
            for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                var setting = rows[i];
                app.locals.setting.Name = setting.Value;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

There are however two problems I am facing:

1) The app.use calls the settings code every time I go to a new page. I just want this code to be called only once when the user logs in.

2) The app.locals are not set. If I do a debug app.locals.SUPPORT_EMAIL as undefined.

Any suggestions or ideas on how this can improve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, two things.  app.use will, in fact, happen on every request.  The easiest way to deal with your need is to simply have that middleware check for app.user and if it's not there call next() without doing anything else.  So the middleware is called but doesn't try to set locals.

Second issue, your function that sets app.locals doesn't actually use the parameters you're passing it (note the function signature in your second code block), *and* it is async, so there's a good chance that the middleware is calling next() before it's ever executed. Change the function signature to:

function(user, locals, callback)

and then have the middleware pass 'next' as the callback.  The locals object you pass should actually be res.locals as you only want to set the variable for that response, not the whole app.

Comment: thanks for the solution. I am actually going to use app.locals.SETTING_NAME cause these settings are going to be used during the lifetime of the app. Another thing I wanted to ask was, is there a limit on the number of app.locals we can do? Cause some of the rows that I try to store in locals come as undefined. Even if I hardcode them like app.locals.mysetting = 'hello' and later console.log(app.locals.mysetting); it comes as undefined. Any idea?